# change .htaccess to not pass .js/.css/.jpg requests through to index.php

Tags: mod-rewrite, .htaccess

Hey guys, bit of a mod_rewrite noob, I've got:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

Which I believe says "If the file or directory doesn't exist, pass the request to index.php".
I'd like another line which says "If it's a .jpg, .css, .js - don't pass it to index.php".
Any help appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the 'RewriteRule' line to:

```
RewriteRule !\.(jpg|css|js|gif|png)$ index.php
```